# Disabling all Gmail's April fools

Tags: gmail, google

Is there any way to disable all future [Google's April fools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_April_Fools%27_Day_hoaxes) in Gmail (and even better, in all Google services)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Google has never offered any option to prevent their corporate pranks. Of course, in the past, most have been ones where you actually need to go to a different URL or are something harmless like changing a site theme.

I can pretty much guarantee that they'll never mess with something as important as email ever again. Certainly not after this backlash.

That said, maybe after this most recent debacle they *will* offer a way to opt-out of future April Fool's jokes. But they don't right now.